# Take a screenshot of background app without launching it

Tags: screen-mirroring

I'm running Android 13 on a Samsung device. I have an app that runs in the background. I want to be able to either:

1. take a screenshot of the app's screen without launching it, i.e. while it's still in the background or
2. broadcast or mirror that particular app's screen to a webpage / url or
3. spy on / monitor that app's screen without launching it

Basically I want to obtain the information on the screen of the app without triggering it, because when I do, I will then be forced to take action on the information that's showing, but sometimes it is best to ignore it. Is there a technique that can allow me to do this?

Comment: Welcome! Software recommendation requests are off-topic on this SE, but on-topic on the software Recommendations SE: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com - I have edited your question to remove that part.  Feel free to post the software recommendations request on that SE.

Comment: I am not sure if apps in background are "accessible" at al by any other app, even if it has accessibility request. This means I don't think that what you want to do is possible on a non-rooted Android device. You may get a more detailed answer in forums on automation apps like Tasker, AutomateIt and so on. People often use such apps may be able to answer you if it is possible with or without root.